# can't uninstall pyserial to fix issues

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, python-3.5, pyserial

I wanna fix this error 
pyserial and serial already installed in Raspberry Pi 
but am still getting this error

```
 from serial import Serial  # Importing the serial library to communicate with Arduino
ImportError: cannot import name 'Serial'
```

When I tried to uninstall pyserial this the result

```
Cannot uninstall 'pyserial'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

how to solve this problem please

Comment: my file name testing.py

Comment: `pyserial` is a python - only library to my knowledge, so all you should need to do is delete the directory from your "site-packages"

Comment: not in site and disk packages

Comment: then use `import serial; print(serial.__file__)` to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo pip install -U pyserial
sudo pip3 install -U pyserial
```

I think pyserial has to be installed as root, for all users (the -U) for with versions for python 2 and 3, for it to work

If you don't have pip, get it from

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: I tried the command; the result 'Cannot uninstall 'pyserial'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
'

Comment: `sudo pip3 install --ignore-installed -U pyserial`
Installing pyserial with the latest version while ignoring the installed version by distutils worked for me